# mysql_fetch_array/row only fetch 1 data

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is probably quite simple.

```
$q = "SELECT id FROM users
        WHERE name LIKE '%$u%' OR active LIKE '%$u%'";
        echo $q;
$u = mysql_query($q) or die("There is a server error : " . mysql_error());
$u = mysql_fetch_array($u);
        print_r($u);
```

But it returns me

```
[id] => 6
```

When I execute the query in Mysql Workbench it returns

```
6
7
8
```

It's probably a fetching problem but I don't understand why.
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` only returns one row. To get more rows, you need a loop.

Also `mysql_fetch_array()` returns both a string association and a integral indexing.
What you want to use is `mysql_fetch_assoc()` like so:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($u)) {
   echo $data['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `mysql_fetch_array` only returns one row. To get more rows, it works in a loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($u)) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

However, do read my comment regarding the use of `mysql_*` functions. This one:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for
>   new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun
>   the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red
>   box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
>   statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you
>   can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose.
>   If you care to learn, [here is good PDO
>   tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `mysql_fetch_array($u)` without a while loop returns a single record. To fetch the whole result set you need to use `mysql_fetch_array($u)` with a while loop. For instance:

```
$q = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$u%' OR active LIKE '%$u%'";
$u = mysql_query($q) or die("There is a server error : " . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($u))
{
print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches a single row - you need to iterate through your result set to get at the rest of the results.